# $E(\min(X,n))$ where $X$ is a random variable with values in $\mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

"Simplify" $E(\min(X,n))$ where $X$ is a random variable with values in $\mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My idea:

$$\begin{align}E(\min(X,n)) &= \int \min(X,n)\,\mathrm dP \\&= \int_{\{X \geq n\}} n\,\mathrm dP + \int_{\{X < n\}} X\,\mathrm dP \\&= n P(\{X \geq n\}) +  \int_{\{X < n\}} X\,\mathrm dP\end{align}$$

But rumour has it, that this still can be simplified. How?

Comment: Not sure, if I remember correctly, but it looked somewhat like: $E(X)(1-P(X> n))$. But I do not know how to get there.

Comment: Such a formula involving $E(X)$  cannot be correct (uunless $P(X\ge n)=0$) because $E(X)$ can be arbitrarily large (simply replace each outcome  $\ge n$ with an outcome a gazillion times larger)

Comment: Define "Simplify". Note that the formula "still can be simplified" in your post comes as a surprise since the computations before it are no "simplification", actually.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{\{X<n\}} XdP = \int XdP - \int_{\{X\geq n\}} XdP = E(X)-\int_{\{X\geq n\}} XdP$$.

Now $P(X\geq n)=\int_{\{X\geq n\}} dP$. So this gives you:

$$E(X) - \int_{\{X\geq n\}} (X-n)dP$$

Not sure if that counts as simpler. Unless you know more about $X$, I'm not sure how much better you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do more than rewriting the second integral as a finite sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\cdot P(\{i\}).
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{i=1}^n P\{X \ge i \}$.  This follows from the identity  $EN = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P\{N \ge n \}$  when  $N$  takes on only nonnegative integer values.